# Preseed - Skip prompt for apps installed via "d-i pkgsel/include string"

Tags: preseed

I am installing ocsinventory-agent with "d-i pkgsel/include string ocsinventory-agent" in my preseed script. It puts up a prompt asking for the server type, which i want to skip and let the pressed script continue without user interaction.

How can I stop ocsinventory-agent from prompting for the server type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it can be done with

```
d-i pkgsel/include string ocsinventory-agent
ocsinventory-agent ocsinventory-agent/method select http
ocsinventory-agent ocsinventory-agent/server string https://<server>/ocsinventory
```